# When/How is a BLE GATT Notify/Indicate is send on physical layer

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I read the bluetooth core spec. V4.2 /BLE (..)

The communication in connection state is **always**  master initiated, slave returns data afterwards. 
The master here is a GATT client talking to GATT server (peripheral device).

I do not understand the GATT Feature "notify" respectively how it works via the lower layers when the master always has to request before sending data.

Someone knows how it works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BLE is timeslotted. In connected state, there are *connection events* that happen periodically, with an interval called *connectionInterval*.

Each connection event is master initiated, which means the master sends the first packet within the connection event.

In order to keep the connection alive, slave **has** to send a packet (and get it acknowledged) at least once every *supervisionTimeout*. There are other timeouts that make the slave respond before that anyway, one of which is the *slaveLatency*, i.e. the number of connection events a slave can ignore before having to respond to master (even if not responding is not a cause for disconnection, it can cause other problems in the protocol, and thus disconnections). On the other hand, master should send a packet on each connection event.

*connectionInterval*, *slaveLatency* and *supervisionTimeout* are the timing part of the *connection parameters* in the spec.  Connection interval ranges from 7.5 ms to 4 seconds, *slaveLatency* from 0 (then slave should respond on every connection event) to the number of connection events corresponding to *supervisionTimeout* / 2. (See 6.B.4.5.1 for the full definition)

So, basically, any payload (including GATT notifications) is queued in the slave or master's stack buffers until the next connection event happens. Whatever the direction (slave to master or master to slave), party has to wait for the next connection event to sends its packets.

Inside a given connection event, each party sends a packet in turn, optionally without any useful payload, until nobody has nothing to send any more. (See 6.B.4.5.6)

That means a notification is queued at most for *connectionInterval*, if radio gets the packet transmitted on the first try.

That's why connection parameters have to be negotiated properly, and that's also why they are different depending on the device type. For instance, a HID (mouse, keyboard, remote control) is generally allowed to connect with a connection interval under 10 ms, while heart rate monitor usually gets a connection interval over a second.

Comment: thank you. so the data (stream) from the upper layers is filled inside the packets  somehow over time (?)   there are no special radio telegrams for each purpose. 

I have to desgin a multiprotocol radio  implementation using BLE and another proprietary protocol an the same radio hardware. So i have to  evaluate if its possible at first.

Comment: At the radio level, for data channel packets, they are all the same format. They contain a header that describes the contained payload type. That's basic encapsulation and layering. See 6.b.2.4. For the rest of what you have to design, that could be another question by itself.

Comment: The design (evaluation) is an upgrade for an existing nordic ESB (enh. shock burst)  protocol/application - Its fully asynchronous. both should be run at the same time.I think when running both protocols at the same time it is not possible to achieve 100% service for the existing protocol.

Comment: Nordic can probably comment about interworking of ESB and BLE with their stacks.